# Calculate confidence intervals on and extract regression summary stats from tidy bootstrapped models on grouped data

Tags: r, bootstrapping, tidymodels, broom, rsample

I want to calculate confidence intervals on a distribution of slope estimates from bootstrapped linear regression models AND extract regression summary statistics (e.g., r.squared) for each of the bootstrapped models on grouped data. I figured out how to calculate the confidence intervals on these data using `dplyr::group_modify()` and `rsample::int_pctl` (related question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68946020/bootstrap-resampling-and-tidy-regression-models-with-grouped-nested-data)), but I can't figure out how to keep the regression summary stats (e.g., using `broom::glance()`) with each model at the same time that I calculate the confidence intervals.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(tidymodels)

set.seed(27)

# Here are the data
dat <- 
  structure(list(site = c("mb", "mb", "mb", "mb", "mb", "mb", "mb", 
  "mb", "sp", "sp", "sp", "sp", "sp", "sp", "sp", "sp"), year = c(2015, 
  2015, 2015, 2015, 2015, 2015, 2015, 2015, 2015, 2015, 2015, 2015, 
  2015, 2015, 2015, 2015), yday = c(15, 15, 35, 35, 48, 48, 69, 
  69, 15, 15, 37, 37, 49, 49, 69, 69), samp_depth_cat2 = structure(c(1L, 
  1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("Mid-2", 
  "Bottom"), class = "factor"), analyte = c("NO3", "NO3", "NO3", 
  "NO3", "NO3", "NO3", "NO3", "NO3", "NH4", "NH4", "NH4", "NH4", 
  "NH4", "NH4", "NH4", "NH4"), conc = c(44.8171069465267, 44.7775358035268, 
  33.3678662097523, 33.0710828871279, 25.8427604055115, 26.9309658742058, 
  23.7585524380667, 17.5240386949382, 8.35832733633183, 9.29280745341615, 
  10.0797380595417, 10.2322058970515, 13.7930668951239, 15.6226805882773, 
  25.3003042764332, 16.8723637466981)), row.names = c(NA, -16L), class = c("tbl_df", 
  "tbl", "data.frame"))

# This is how I bootstrap the regressions and calculate confidence intervals:
  lm_boot_CI <-
    dat %>% 
    group_by(site, year, samp_depth_cat2, analyte) %>% 
    group_modify(
      ~ bootstraps(., times = 100, apparent = TRUE) %>%
        mutate(
          model = map(splits, ~ lm(conc ~ yday, data = .)),
          coefs = map(model, tidy)
        ) %>%
        int_pctl(coefs)
    )

# I am able to keep the row of summary stats for each model and unnest it 
# IF I do a separate bootstrapping routine on the same data:
  lm_boot_R2 <-
    dat %>% 
    group_by(site, year, samp_depth_cat2, analyte) %>% 
    group_modify(
      ~ bootstraps(., times = 100, apparent = TRUE) %>%
        mutate(
          model = map(splits, ~ lm(conc ~ yday, data = .)),
          coefs = map(model, tidy),
          glanced = map(model, glance)
        )
    ) %>% 
    unnest(glanced)
```

So the question is, how do I integrate these two code chunks to accomplish both at once on the same bootstrapped models (i.e., use `int_pctl()` and `glance()`)?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if you can do this all in one go, because the "shape" of the output you are looking for is so different. I think this makes `group_modify()` not a great option since it is mostly for "dataframe in, dataframe out".

One way to approach this would be to start out by training all the models, using `map()` two layers deep:

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(tidymodels)
#> Registered S3 method overwritten by 'tune':
#>   method                   from   
#>   required_pkgs.model_spec parsnip

set.seed(27)

# Here are the data
dat <- 
    structure(list(site = c("mb", "mb", "mb", "mb", "mb", "mb", "mb", 
                            "mb", "sp", "sp", "sp", "sp", "sp", "sp", "sp", "sp"), 
                   year = c(2015, 
                            2015, 2015, 2015, 2015, 2015, 2015, 2015, 2015, 2015, 2015, 2015, 
                            2015, 2015, 2015, 2015), yday = c(15, 15, 35, 35, 48, 48, 69, 
                                                              69, 15, 15, 37, 37, 49, 49, 69, 69), 
                   samp_depth_cat2 = structure(c(1L, 
                                                 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), 
                                               .Label = c("Mid-2", 
                                                          "Bottom"), class = "factor"), 
                   analyte = c("NO3", "NO3", "NO3", 
                               "NO3", "NO3", "NO3", "NO3", "NO3", "NH4", "NH4", "NH4", "NH4", 
                               "NH4", "NH4", "NH4", "NH4"), conc = c(44.8171069465267, 44.7775358035268, 
                                                                     33.3678662097523, 33.0710828871279, 25.8427604055115, 26.9309658742058, 
                                                                     23.7585524380667, 17.5240386949382, 8.35832733633183, 9.29280745341615, 
                                                                     10.0797380595417, 10.2322058970515, 13.7930668951239, 15.6226805882773, 
                                                                     25.3003042764332, 16.8723637466981)), 
              row.names = c(NA, -16L), class = c("tbl_df", 
                                                 "tbl", "data.frame"))

lm_boot_mods <- 
    dat %>%
    nest(data = c(conc, yday)) %>%
    mutate(boots = map(
        data,  
        ~ bootstraps(., times = 100, apparent = TRUE) %>%
            mutate(model = map(.$splits, ~ lm(conc ~ yday, data = .)),
                   coefs = map(model, tidy),
                   glanced = map(model, glance))
    ))

lm_boot_mods
#> # A tibble: 2 × 6
#>   site   year samp_depth_cat2 analyte data             boots                 
#>   <chr> <dbl> <fct>           <chr>   <list>           <list>                
#> 1 mb     2015 Mid-2           NO3     <tibble [8 × 2]> <bootstraps [101 × 5]>
#> 2 sp     2015 Bottom          NH4     <tibble [8 × 2]> <bootstraps [101 × 5]>
```

That `boots` column has the models plus the coefficients. Now you can compute the bootstrap confidence intervals, and get out the per-model `glance()` results.

```r
lm_boot_ci <-
    lm_boot_mods %>%
    mutate(pctl = map(boots, ~ int_pctl(., coefs)),
           glanced = map(boots, "glanced"))
#> Warning: Recommend at least 1000 non-missing bootstrap resamples for terms:
#> `(Intercept)`, `yday`.

#> Warning: Recommend at least 1000 non-missing bootstrap resamples for terms:
#> `(Intercept)`, `yday`.

lm_boot_ci
#> # A tibble: 2 × 8
#>   site   year samp_depth_cat2 analyte data             boots     pctl    glanced
#>   <chr> <dbl> <fct>           <chr>   <list>           <list>    <list>  <list> 
#> 1 mb     2015 Mid-2           NO3     <tibble [8 × 2]> <bootstr… <tibbl… <list …
#> 2 sp     2015 Bottom          NH4     <tibble [8 × 2]> <bootstr… <tibbl… <list …

lm_boot_ci %>%
    select(pctl, glanced)
#> # A tibble: 2 × 2
#>   pctl             glanced     
#>   <list>           <list>      
#> 1 <tibble [2 × 6]> <list [101]>
#> 2 <tibble [2 × 6]> <list [101]>
```

<sup>Created on 2021-09-08 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

These are quite different "shapes", though, like I said, so I'm not sure what you want to do from here.

Comment: She beautiful, thank you. I was able to unnest `pctl` but when I tried `unnest(glanced)` nothing happened. Normally my `glanced` column is a list column of tibbles, but it appears this time its a list of list. Any ideas how to unnest the summary stats for each model? Still learning how to work with list columns.

Comment: You'll need to _only_ `select()` the `glanced` column, and then you should be able to unnest. Alternatively, from `lm_boot_mods`, you could use something like `map_dfr()` if you _only_ handle the summary stats per model and not the bootstrap confidence intervals.