# Bootstrapping using tidymodels from a list of dataframes in R

Tags: r, tidymodels

I am running a model using `tidymodels`, where split the data by group and run regressions on each individual dataframe. This works well. However, now I also need to bootstrap my results. I'm not sure how to build this into my existing code.

My original code looks something like this:

```
library(dplyr)

year <- rep(2014:2018, length.out=10000)
group <- sample(c(0,1,2,3,4,5,6), replace=TRUE, size=10000)
value <- sample(10000, replace=T)
female <- sample(c(0,1), replace=TRUE, size=10000)
smoker <- sample(c(0,1), replace=TRUE, size=10000)
dta <- data.frame(year=year, group=group, value=value, female=female, smoker=smoker)

# cut the dataset into list
table_list <- dta %>%
  group_by(year, group) %>%
  group_split()

# fit model per subgroup
model_list <- lapply(table_list, function(x) glm(smoker ~ female, data=x,
                                                 family=binomial(link="probit")))
# predict
pred_list <- lapply(model_list, function(x) predict.glm(x, type = "response"))
```

I would like to bootstrap with replacement to obtain the bootstrapped predicted values. My gut feeling is that I should split the dataset further by creating random samples when I create the table_list. But how exactly do I do that?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Did you consider the [`boot` package](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/boot/versions/1.3-28/topics/boot)?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Bootstrap resampling and tidy regression models with grouped/nested data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68946020/bootstrap-resampling-and-tidy-regression-models-with-grouped-nested-data)

Comment: @dario: This is a great start, but at the end I need the actual predicted values. Thanks.

Comment: *"This is a great start, but at the end I need the actual predicted values"* .. I don't understand why you think the answers presented in the two links above would not give predictions, that's kind of the reason for any bootstrap procedure ;). The packages just help you with the sampling (by the way, fyi:, bootstrapping is **by definition** sampling with replacement ;) )

Comment: @dario: I'm not sure we are talking about the same thing. I need to calculate the predicted(fitted) values for each bootstrapped sample. I'm sure I could get there using the links above, but I just don't know how to go about it and there is little in the documentation on how to predict using the boot package.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is fairly complex, with the grouping and the bootstrapping, so I would probably approach it [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69110762/5468471), using `map()` two layers deep:

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(tidymodels)
#> Registered S3 method overwritten by 'tune':
#>   method                   from   
#>   required_pkgs.model_spec parsnip

year <- rep(2014:2018, length.out=10000)
group <- sample(c(0,1,2,3,4,5,6), replace=TRUE, size=10000)
value <- sample(10000, replace=T)
female <- sample(c(0,1), replace=TRUE, size=10000)
smoker <- sample(c(0,1), replace=TRUE, size=10000)
dta <- tibble(year=year, group=group, value=value, female=female, smoker=smoker)


glm_boot_mods <- 
  dta %>%
  nest(data = c(-year, -group)) %>%
  mutate(boots = map(
    data,  
    ~ bootstraps(., times = 20) %>%
      mutate(model = map(.$splits, ~ glm(smoker ~ female, data = analysis(.x),
                                         family = binomial(link = "probit"))),
             preds = map2(model, .$splits, ~predict(.x, newdata = assessment(.y))))
    ))


glm_boot_mods
#> # A tibble: 35 × 4
#>     year group data               boots                
#>    <int> <dbl> <list>             <list>               
#>  1  2014     1 <tibble [288 × 3]> <bootstraps [20 × 4]>
#>  2  2015     4 <tibble [273 × 3]> <bootstraps [20 × 4]>
#>  3  2016     3 <tibble [301 × 3]> <bootstraps [20 × 4]>
#>  4  2017     2 <tibble [282 × 3]> <bootstraps [20 × 4]>
#>  5  2018     0 <tibble [276 × 3]> <bootstraps [20 × 4]>
#>  6  2014     3 <tibble [279 × 3]> <bootstraps [20 × 4]>
#>  7  2016     2 <tibble [314 × 3]> <bootstraps [20 × 4]>
#>  8  2018     1 <tibble [296 × 3]> <bootstraps [20 × 4]>
#>  9  2014     0 <tibble [304 × 3]> <bootstraps [20 × 4]>
#> 10  2015     6 <tibble [288 × 3]> <bootstraps [20 × 4]>
#> # … with 25 more rows
```

The first `map()` creates the bootstrap resamples for each grouping, and then we go one layer deeper and for *each resample* fit a model and predict for the heldout observations for that resample. You can see what that looks like inside here for the first group:

```r
glm_boot_mods %>%
  head(1) %>% 
  pull(boots)
#> [[1]]
#> # Bootstrap sampling 
#> # A tibble: 20 × 4
#>    splits            id          model  preds      
#>    <list>            <chr>       <list> <list>     
#>  1 <split [288/111]> Bootstrap01 <glm>  <dbl [111]>
#>  2 <split [288/93]>  Bootstrap02 <glm>  <dbl [93]> 
#>  3 <split [288/103]> Bootstrap03 <glm>  <dbl [103]>
#>  4 <split [288/106]> Bootstrap04 <glm>  <dbl [106]>
#>  5 <split [288/109]> Bootstrap05 <glm>  <dbl [109]>
#>  6 <split [288/109]> Bootstrap06 <glm>  <dbl [109]>
#>  7 <split [288/92]>  Bootstrap07 <glm>  <dbl [92]> 
#>  8 <split [288/111]> Bootstrap08 <glm>  <dbl [111]>
#>  9 <split [288/99]>  Bootstrap09 <glm>  <dbl [99]> 
#> 10 <split [288/111]> Bootstrap10 <glm>  <dbl [111]>
#> 11 <split [288/102]> Bootstrap11 <glm>  <dbl [102]>
#> 12 <split [288/104]> Bootstrap12 <glm>  <dbl [104]>
#> 13 <split [288/115]> Bootstrap13 <glm>  <dbl [115]>
#> 14 <split [288/111]> Bootstrap14 <glm>  <dbl [111]>
#> 15 <split [288/108]> Bootstrap15 <glm>  <dbl [108]>
#> 16 <split [288/110]> Bootstrap16 <glm>  <dbl [110]>
#> 17 <split [288/110]> Bootstrap17 <glm>  <dbl [110]>
#> 18 <split [288/111]> Bootstrap18 <glm>  <dbl [111]>
#> 19 <split [288/103]> Bootstrap19 <glm>  <dbl [103]>
#> 20 <split [288/109]> Bootstrap20 <glm>  <dbl [109]>
```

<sup>Created on 2021-11-02 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Notice that there are predictions for the heldout observations for each resample. Depending on what you want to do, you can use `unnest()` on the columns of `glm_boot_mods` you need to handle next.